# can selenium scroll down browser and only parse new content at the same time?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

The web page that I want to parse has more than several thousand links. It also has infinite scrolling feature, which means I need to use send_keys( Keys.PAGE_DOWN ) in Selenium to extend the page for more contents.

Is it possible to use selenium to scroll down the browser and meanwhile only parse the new content? I don't want to repeatedly parse the old contents or wait the web page reaches the bottom and then parse, since the webpage has a large amount of links.

Any suggestion? If there is a better library for python that can help me do that, please also let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple loop that extracts only the newly rendered links using xpath. Without knowing more about the page you're parsing, I'll assume that all `a` tags are fair game:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
links = []

while True:
    # Get any links beyond the ones we already have
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        "//a[position()>{}]".format(len(links))

    # If there are no more links, stop
    if not len(elements):
        break

    # "Parse" the links
    links += elements

    # Page down to trigger load of next batch
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```